# Trouble when build android game from unity

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I have created a 2D game and tried to build it on Android platform to an `.apk` file, but I got this message:

```
"Make sure that you are using at least jdk 6 (1.6). The latest can be obtained from the Oracle".
```

I have intalled the latest Android SDK and I'm using JDK 8 (1.8). Can anyone help?

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu or MSBuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add the path to the JDK to your PATH environment variable.

To check if this is true try to run **javac** from the console, if it complains about not knowing the command then you need to add the path to your environment.

If you are on a linux you can do something like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH;path_to_jdk
```

Note: this will change the path only for this session, if you want it to be permanent you need to change the content of your ~/.bashrc

Comment: Hey hades, thanks for your help, but there is a problem when I run javac from console, the command prompt window said:"javac is not recognized as an internal or external command , operable program or batch file".

Comment: yup, this means that the shell doesn't know how to find javac on your system, you need to change your PATH to reflect this, have you tried the export command from my answer?

Comment: thank you so much, the problem is I start the command prompt window before I change the PATH environment variable, it work fine after I restart the command prompt window. Thanks!

Comment: try updating your ~/.bashrc by adding the export PATH to it, this way the PATH var gets set to include jdk everytime you login with that user